# Change initial Interface Controller for Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue, apple-watch

Does anyone know how to do this in the ExtensionDelegate? Here's how I did it in the AppDelegate for iPhone

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStory" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"2ndScreen"];                                                                                                           
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: You can do it in info.plist. I can post an answer if that solution will satisfy you.